# using KVM & screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I have 2 PCs which are using same keyboard, mouse and screen by kvm.
If I connecting to PC1 by Teamviewer while the PC2 is selected to be used by KVM, I can see that the resolution of screen of PC is configured to the minimal one (600*800).

If I'll switch on KVM to PC1 the resolution would be changed to the configured one.

What could be done so that the resolution would not change while on KVM I select PC2.